# Full Slide Bootstrap

Tags: html, bootstrap-3

Olá, adicionei um slide carousel no site em que estou desenvolvendo, e gostaria que ficasse com width: 100% em meu header, mas mesmo adicionando essa propriedade ela não é aplicada,como na imagem 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Podem me ajudar ?

Esse é meu index:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html >
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Auto Jet - Serviços Automotivoss</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/geral.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <header>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="logo">
                    <a href="index.html">
                        <img src="images/logo-home.svg" alt="logo topo">
                </div>
            <div class="links">
                <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                <li><a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a></li>
                <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
            </ul>   
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="slide3.png" alt="Auto Jet - Serviços Automotivos" style="width:100%; height:524px;">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item active">
                        <img src="slide2.png" alt="Auto Jet - Serviços Automotivos" style="width:100%; height:524px;">
                    </div>

                    <div class="item">
                        <img src="slide.png" alt="Auto Jet - Serviços Automotivos" style="width:100%; height:524px;">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
                </a>
                <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Próxima</span>
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        </header>
    </div>
         <main>
              <section class="sobre">    
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="itens">
                            <div class="imagem">
                                 <img src="images/logo-quem-somos.svg" alt="Logo Quem somos">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="textos">
                            <p><strong>A AutoJet®</strong> é uma empresa especializada em serviços automotivos,atuando a mais de 10 anos no ramo de mecanica, com professionais capacitados para atender ao que for preciso para seu veiculo, visando atendimento rapido e efeciente...</p>
        
                            <a href="sobre.html" class="botao medio"> <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Continue Lendo</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </section>
         </main>
        <footer>
            <div class="logo-rodape">
                 <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="images/logo-rodape.svg" alt="logo-rodape">
                 <a/>
            <p> Todos os Direiros Reservados Auto Jet Serviços Automotivos ® - 2017 </p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

O seu slider não ocupa toda a área porque ele esta dentro de uma `div`com uma `class="container"` o que não permite que ele ocupe toda a área.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Auto Jet - Serviços Automotivoss</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/home.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/geral.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/plugins.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="index.html">
                    <img src="images/logo-home.svg" alt="logo topo">
              </a>
            </div>
            <div class="links">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Inicio</a></li>
                        <li><a href="sobre.html">Sobre</a></li>
                        <li><a href="servicos.html">Serviços</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contato.html">Contato</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="slide3.png" alt="Auto Jet - Serviços Automotivos" style="width:100%; height:524px;">
                </div>
                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="slide2.png" alt="Auto Jet - Serviços Automotivos" style="width:100%; height:524px;">
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <img src="slide.png" alt="Auto Jet - Serviços Automotivos" style="width:100%; height:524px;">
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>
            </a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Próxima</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </header>
   
    <main>
        <section class="sobre">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="itens">
                    <div class="imagem">
                        <img src="images/logo-quem-somos.svg" alt="Logo Quem somos">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="textos">
                    <p><strong>A AutoJet®</strong> é uma empresa especializada em serviços automotivos,atuando a mais de 10 anos no ramo de mecanica, com professionais capacitados para atender ao que for preciso para seu veiculo, visando atendimento rapido e efeciente...</p>
                    <a href="sobre.html" class="botao medio"> <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> Continue Lendo</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="logo-rodape">
            <a href="index.html">
                <img src="images/logo-rodape.svg" alt="logo-rodape">
          </a>
                <p> Todos os Direiros Reservados Auto Jet Serviços Automotivos ® - 2017 </p>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado Funcionou corretamente, o unico problema é que eu não estou conseguindo que meu slide tome o header , a parte do topo onde esta o menu fica Branco, como posso resolver esse problema ?

Comment: @luismatheus tenta usar o carousel do proprio bootstrap vai ser melhor para seu problema: **http://bootstrap1.com/pt/examples/carousel.html** . Ou se não quiser utilizar o carousel você pode tentar colocar um css:`#myCarousel { position: relative; margin-top: -113px; width: 100%;  z-index: -1;}`